# Page glitches unless error_reporting is -1?

Tags: php

On my site, if error_reporting is not -1, the page entirely glitches out

I made two pages, both exactly the same except that testblog.php has error_reporting(0);, whereas blog.php has error_reporting(-1);

These are the pages:
http://pirates-online-rewritten.com/blog.php
http://pirates-online-rewritten.com/testblog.php

This is my code (please fix the format someone, I don't know how):

```
<?php
include "header2.php";
include "connect.php";
error_reporting(-1);
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID'])));
$getPost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blogs WHERE ID='$ID'");
$gP = mysql_fetch_object($getPost);
?>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="626" summary="layout table">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="626">
                        <!-- BEGIN CENTER CONTENT -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="626" summary="layout table">
                            <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"     width="626"><img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/Title_currentnews.gif" width="626" height="86" border="0" alt="Current News" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="top">

                                <td background="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/parch_left.gif">
                                    <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/dot.gif" width="57" height="327" border="0" alt="" />
                                </td>
                                <td background="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/parch_bg.gif">
<?php

echo $gP->Title, $gP->Body;

?>
                                </td>
                                <td background="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/parch_right.gif">
                                    <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/dot.gif" width="58" height="327" border="0" alt="" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" width="626">
                                    <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/parch_bot.gif" alt="parch_bot.jpg" width="626" height="55" border="0" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <!-- SET THE MENU LAYOUT -->
                                <td>
                                    <img src="http://www.pirates-online-rewritten.com/images/spacer.gif" height="0" width="0"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- END CENTER CONTENT -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
<?php 
include "footer.php"; 
?>
```

Comment: `$ID = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID'])));` are you sure you need this? I would have just `intval`'d it

Comment: You should use E_* constants instead. Never rely on the numeric values they bear, as they can change. Like, in your case you could use E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE for example

Comment: I prefer using that @RoyalBg

Comment: @Oleg Dubas what do you mean?

Comment: so when error reporting is on, what error is displayed?

Comment: @Sam I am talking about your `error_reporting(-1);` It isn't a correct usage.

Comment: Just undefined variables, nothing big, I can fix it easily, just wondering what's up with the whole glitched parchment

Comment: @OlegDubas how do I fix it?

Comment: the page glitches out most likely because the html is being invalidated when php prints the errors, the solution is to fix the errors

Comment: @andrew it's the other way around, the error makes the page work, without errors it breaks. I tried echoing text above it instead of the errors, but it has the same error as testblog.php

Comment: well I don't know what -1 would produce, you should use the constants as @OlegDubas says. see here http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: @andrew -1 is similar to E_ALL I believe.

Comment: Its your style, I think. Unless it has some contents, the bground will repeat. And the error happened to give it contents.

Comment: And from my IDE some of your `div`s and `td`s tags were highlited as invalid code. Might be because of no matching closing tags.